# How to set the default Selected Item of List View in Master Detail Page

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am referencing the Xamarin Master Detail Sample Application. In that, we are using the ListView inside the Master-Detail Page. We want to set the First Item as Selected Item at Startup of MasterDetailPage.

[MasterDetaiPagel Sample App Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/)

Comment: What did you try so far? There is a SelectedItem property you can set.

Comment: @Depechie: I tried with Selected Item property, but the menu item is not coming highlighted.

Comment: using https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/MasterDetailPageNavigation/XAML/MainPage.xaml file  you can set your default selected page. In this sample they have sets Contact Page as selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to handle this is to stop relying on the built in `ListView` selection styling and handle background changing on selection yourself. Unfortunately disabling the default selection styling requires custom renders.

Implement the `ViewCell` renderers below to disable default selection styling. Then you just need to bind your `ViewCell` child control's `BackgroundColor` to an `IsSelected` property on your model or how ever you want to do it.

When you want to set a default selected item:

```
mySelectedItem.IsSelected = true; //Assuming this bubbles up a PropertyChanged event to the ListView

MyListView.SelectedItem = mySelectedItem;
// Maybes scroll to the item here if necessary
```

The code below is not perfect so let me know if any improvements can be made.

**Xamarin Forms ViewCell**

```
public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell { }
```

**Android ViewCell Custom Renderer**

```
public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer {

    protected override View GetCellCore(Cell item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context) {
        View cellCore = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

        if(parent is ListView listView) {
            listView.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
            listView.CacheColorHint = Color.White;
        }

        cellCore.SetBackground(GetUnpressedBackground());

        return cellCore;
    }


    private StateListDrawable GetUnpressedBackground() {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        //states.AddState(new[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.White));
        //states.AddState(new[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateFocused }, new ColorDrawable(Color.White));
        //states.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(Color.Blue.ToAndroid()));

        return states;
    }
}
```

**iOS ViewCell Custom Renderer**

```
public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer {

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv) {
        UITableViewCell  cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        if(cell != null) {
            // Disable native cell selection color style - set as *Transparent*
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            //cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)cell.Bounds.Width, (float)cell.Bounds.Height)) {
            //    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            //};
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: We are working with UWP. Where we need to set default item in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @AnkitJain Look for a UWP ViewCell renderer, if it is needed on UWP, and then follow the instructions above.